# what is est in filter sparkUI sql tab

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying to debug my spark UI, and in the SQL tab of spark UI getting this red mark on filter description, trying to figure out what does it mean.

[Spark UI sql Tab SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YRso.png)

Answer (score 0):

For CBO, thus based on Hive, use the Spark SQL UI page to see the executed plan and "accuracy of the statistics". Red stuff what was estimated and nX how close, more specifically error factor.